# YUI Editor: How to use CSS to format content of editor window?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yui, richtextbox, yui-editor

I've implemented the [YUI Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) and would like to apply a CSS to change the look of the text the user is working on **inside** the rich text editor.

I'm working with the [yui_editor plugin for ruby on rails](http://github.com/larsklevan/yui_editor/tree/master), but that doesn't mean that a generic answer wouldn't be welcome. It's even OK if you could just point me to the correct API section and/or an example on how to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, I've found the answer myself: This is possible by using the `css` *Configuration Attribute* ([YUI API](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor.html)).

To implement this with the yui_editor plugin on rails, I had to insert the css-attribute as seen on the following code snippet in `config/yui_editor.yml`:

```
editor_config_javascript: "
{
  handleSubmit: true,
  autoHeight: false,
  css: 'YADA { FOO: BAR; }',
  collapse: true,
  toolbar: ...
}
```

That's it, works like a charm.